# How to eqally split an array to 3 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have a one dimensional  array as follows. (It may dynamically extend to any length)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [city] => Trivandrum
        [citykey] => ab5416c6
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [city] => Kochi
        [citykey] => 85cb7d9c
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [city] => Alappuzha
        [citykey] => 4d5f200e
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [city] => Mumbai
        [citykey] => 47d98024
    )

)
```

Now I would like to split it to 3 arrays . I mean I would like to split an array in to 3 arrays as follows.

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [city] => Trivandrum
        [citykey] => ab5416c6
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [city] => Mumbai
        [citykey] => 47d98024
    )

)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [city] => Kochi
        [citykey] => 85cb7d9c
    )

)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [city] => Alappuzha
        [citykey] => 4d5f200e
    )

)
```

Comment: Depending on how you want it split into 3 different arrays, [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) may be helpful.

Comment: What do you want each array to contain? It's not clear from the question. Could you provide the expected output from this four element array?

Comment: I would like to get this output. Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [city] => Trivandrum
        [citykey] => ab5416c6
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [city] => Mumbai
        [citykey] => 47d98024
    )

)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [city] => Kochi
        [citykey] => 85cb7d9c
    )

)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [city] => Alappuzha
        [citykey] => 4d5f200e
    )

)

Comment: Why do you want to create 3 independent array variables? Why can't they be a part of a parent array, like they are now. If you really want to create 3 different arrays, what names are you going to given them?

Comment: I just trying to split an array in to three. If the parent array contains 5 elements , then 1st,4th will go to the first array , 2nd and 5th will go to the second array and 3rd will go to the third array. Please help me

Comment: What if it has 4 or 3 items ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera: That's shown in the example. As far as I understand, they should be equal, and if there are any remainders, they should go from the first to last.

Comment: If there is 3 elements in the array, then the first element will go to first array , 2nd element will go to second array and 3rd element will go to the third array. If there is 4 elements in the array, then the 1st and 4th elements will go to the first array, 2nd element will go to the 2nd array and 3rd element will go to the third array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = range(1,4); // example input array of 4 items
$n = 3; // number of pieces you want in the output array $b

$b = array_fill(0, $n, array());
for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) {
    $b[$i % $n][] = $a[$i];
}

print_r($b);

// if you need to split them out
list($a1,$a2,$a3) = $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?
$i=0;
$array=Array(0=> Array("city" => 'Trivandrum',
        "citykey" => 'ab5416c6'
    ),
1 => Array
    (
        "city" => 'Kochi',
        "citykey" => '85cb7d9c'
    ),
2 => Array
    (
        "city" => 'Alappuzha',
        "citykey" => '4d5f200e'
    ),
3 => Array
    (
        "city" => 'Mumbai',
        "citykey" => '47d98024'
    )
);
$array_0=array();
$array_1=array();
$array_2=array();
foreach ($array as $value)
  {
  $name='array_'.$i%3;
  $temp[0]=$value;
  $$name=array_merge_recursive($$name, $temp);
  $i++;
  }
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_0);
print_r($array_1);
print_r($array_2);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Your original array should be in variable **$array**